# Is there $r>0$ such that the norm $[f]_r:=\sup_{n \ge 1} \|1_{B(y_n, r)} f\|_{L^p}$ is equivalent to $\|f \|:=\sup_{y \in Y}\|1_{B(y,1)}f\|_{L^p}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, norms

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(Y, d)$ be a separable metric space,
- $\mathcal B$ Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$,
- $\nu$ a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $Y$,
- $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space,
- $L^0(Y) := L^0(Y, \nu, E)$ the space of $\nu$-measurable functions from $Y$ to $E$,
- $p \in [1, \infty)$,
- $L^p (Y) := L^p(Y, \nu, E)$ the space of $p$-integrable functions from $Y$ to $E$.

Let $(y_n)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. For $r>0$ and $f \in L^0(Y)$, we define
$$
\begin{align*}
\| f \| &:=  \sup_{y \in Y} \|1_{B(y, 1)} f\|_{L^p}, \\
[f]_r &:= \sup_{n \ge 1} \|1_{B(y_n, r)} f\|_{L^p},
\end{align*}
$$
where $B(y, r)$ is the open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r$.

> Is there $r>0$ such that the norms $\| \cdot \|$ and $[\cdot]_s$ are equivalent?

The answer is affirmative in the special case where $E=\mathbb R$ and $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure of $Y = \mathbb R^d$.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!